# Monodevelop, "no such file or directory" when trying to run a program

Tags: 12.10, directory, disk-usage, monodevelop

I wanted to try to write a C++ program in "Monodevelop" and i use Ubuntu 12.10 as a OS.
But when i finish writing my program (any program) and want to actually run my program, i get this error:

> bash: /home/Username/C++: No such file or directory
>
> Press any key to continue...

That "C++" in "/home/Username/C++" is supposed to be the name of the folder which i wanted to build my project in it and it's name is "c++ projects"
now i understand it is because of the space that is between "c++" and "projects", so my question is, is there a way that i can build and run my program in a directory that has a space inside it's name?
Now i tried writing the same program in "Code::blocks" and have had no problem.
I understand i will have the same "no such file or directory" error if i try to go to a directory that has a space in it's name in the terminal, and it is pretty annoying that i can't have my program ran in the directory that i want it to run. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote your path

e.g.

```
"/home/Username/C++ Projects/MyAwesomeProgram/bin/myawesomeprogram"
```

or escape the space

```
/home/Username/C++\ Projects/MyAwesomeProgram/bin/myawesomeprogram
```

Comment: This works generally speaking except for with Monodevelop it just does not work (for me at least) unless I open the file from using the Monodevelop GUI. opening paths without spaces works as expected. Here is a thread start on that https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410953/how-to-open-a-file-in-monodevelop-with-spaces-in-the-path